# Problem with promise handling using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, error-handling, promise

I'm working on my own project. His main idea is movie reviews.

I'm currently working on the HTTP requests trying to make my code a little better.
I guess I have a problem with my promise handling:

```js
    try {
        let newMovie = await MovieRepository.addNewMovie({
            name: req.body.name,
            year: req.body.year,
            description: req.body.description,
            length: req.body.length,
            genres: req.body.genres,
            totalRating: req.body.totalRating
        });
        return res.status(200).json({ name: newMovie, message: 'Movie added successfully!' });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: errorMessage.addNewMovie });
    }
```

**This code works!** I'm adding a new Movie and I get an OK status as expected.

Quick explaining about my code: I'm using `MovieRepository` where I use mongoose functionality to add a new movie. get all the info I need from the body and send it to the client.

Now, I've tried to change my code a little bit :

```js
let newMovie = await MovieRepository.addNewMovie({
        name: req.body.name,
        year: req.body.year,
        description: req.body.description,
        length: req.body.length,
        genres: req.body.genres,
        totalRating: req.body.totalRating
    }).then(() => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            name: newMovie,
            message: 'Movie added successfully!'
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.status(400).json({
            status: 400,
            message: errorMessage.addNewMovie,
            systemError: error
        });
    });
```

**This code is not working well.**

Here I'm using the promise abilities to use `then` and `catch`. Pay attention that I didn't actually changed anything inside those functionalities.

In this case, the movie added to the database successfully as well, but the client gets status 400.

**Any ideas what's happening here?**

Comment: Can you copy/paste your addNewMovie method please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be way off and incorrect in my understanding (new to JS) but I think `newMovie` is undefined inside your `then` call.

Try changing:

```
.then(() => {
```

to:

```
.then(newMovie => {
```

---

Also, I think your `return` statements in the two approaches (with promises and without promises) aren't doing the same thing -- which may have implications for the rest of your code.

---

This is my limited understanding of the differences between these two approaches:

- First approach assigns the return value of `addNewMovie` to variable `newMovie`, and the outer async function returns whatever `res.status(...).json(...)` returns.
- Second approach assigns the return value of the promise chain   `res.status(...).json(...)` to `newMovie` -- and then the outer async function implicitly/automatically returns `undefined` (if there are no other `return` statements shown).
- If you had moved your `catch` above the `then`, I think that would have allowed you to see that your `addNewMovie` was completing successfully (i.e. the movie was being added to the database), but that your success handler `then` was throwing an error.

I'm sure someone else can give you a better, more formal and accurate explanation.

Comment: that worked, I guess I didn't notice well my new approach.
btw, can you explain me the actual difference between this approaches?